# get array of string php regex

Tags: php, arrays, regex, string

Hello i have a problem with a regexp.

for example i have this text

```
$textMessage = "|nif|<00/00/03364301P>|lat|<not set>|long|<not set>|deviceId|<1F26DE6896ADC816-001346E604E7>|messageId|<70154>";
```

and i want to get an array like this

```
$data = array(
array("nif" => "00/00/03364301P"),
array("lat" => "not set") // etc
```

)

with all data from the string , i tried this function.

```
function getArrayDataSMS($textMessage){
  $regexType = '/\|([a-zA-Z]+)\||<[\d]+>/';
  $rowValueData = preg_match_all($regexType, $textMessage, $matches,   PREG_SET_ORDER);

foreach ($matches as $key => $match) {
  $arrayData[trim($match[1])] = trim($match[2]);
}
return $arrayData;
```

}

but the response is not correct

```
array(2) {
 [0]=>
 string(5) "|nif|"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "nif"
  }

 array(3) {
   [0]=>
     string(6) "<4545>"
   [1]=>
     string(0) ""
   [2]=>
     string(4) "4545"
  }
```

Any idea about this? .

Comment: or just explode it, shift, chunk by twos, foreach assignment to new container

Comment: I don't think using regex is the good way here.

Comment: Do you really want a multidimensional array or just a simple associative array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NON - Regex

> $textMessage = "|nif|<00/00/03364301P>|lat||long||deviceId|<1F26DE6896ADC816-001346E604E7>|messageId|<70154>";

Using the string above, you can use this script to process it into the array that you wanted.

```
$array = explode("|",$textMessage);
var_dump($array);

$data = array();

//Start with 1 since $array[0] is '';
//Assumed first and last characters <> are present and need to be removed
//Feel free to modify as needed

for($i = 1; $i < count($array); $i+=2) {
     $data[] = array($array[$i] => substr($array[$i+1], 1, -1));
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
            [nif] => 00/00/03364301P
        )

    [1] => Array (
            [lat] => not set
        )

    [2] => Array (
            [long] => not set
        )

    [3] => Array (
            [deviceId] => 1F26DE6896ADC816-001346E604E7
        )

    [4] => Array (
            [messageId] => 70154
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$text = "|nif|<00/00/03364301P>|lat|<not set>|long|<not set>|deviceId|<1F26DE6896ADC816-001346E604E7>|messageId|<70154>";
preg_match_all("/\|(\w+?)\|\<(.+?)>/",$text,$a);
$result = array_combine($a[1],$a[2]);
```